# Could anyone tell me why when I press x my Character does not move faster?

Tags: python, pygame

The section of code. After I press x the speed the character moves when I press a/d doesnt change to 30.

```
    speed = 8

    if keys[pygame.K_x]:
        speed = 30

        
    if keys[pygame.K_d]:
        Character_rect.x += speed
    
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        Character_rect.x -= speed
```

Comment: 1. `speed = 8` should be outside any loop you have, otherwise it resets. 2. This code checks the state (or even now, idk what "keys" is, I don't know pygame itself) at the time when instruction pointer is at this line. Let's say python evaluates if with x when you hit a/d - the a/d will be missed. Try holding (not pressing) your key until something happens (*if* the `if`s are properly written - as I said, I don't know what this "keys" is). 3. Look into using events instead to avoid 2.

Comment: Thankyou, I have fixed it now

Answer (score 4):

If you have put this code in a while loop, when the while loop reruns, it resets speed to 8

Comment: Thankyou, I now realise I should have put the speed = 8 variable out of the loop